# open a list of bookmarks in one go?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, browser, bookmarks

How can I open a list of bookmarks into different windows of Android's 2.3.5 browser in one go? For example, how can I set up a bookmark list that opens 3 windows in one go with the pages: www.nytimes.com, www.usatoday.com, www.washingtonpost.com all three of them from just one bookmark that will open the three pages in 3 different browser windows?

Comment: You might beable to set something up in Tasker (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&hl=en) to do this